# PHP- Link in database table to show only one table row

Tags: php, database

I have an assignment where I have to get a database table and display its content, so far so good. But then I need the ID to be a link that shows only that table row with its corresponding data. I can't really figure out how to get that done in PHP.
Could you perhaps give it a go?
I have the opening of the database in a function in another file.

Code:

```
$db = connectToDatabase($dsn);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM jetty");
$stmt->execute();

$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<h1>Content of the database</h1>

<?php
$rows = "";

foreach ($res as $row) {
    $rows .= "<tr><td>{$row["id"]}</td>";
    $rows .= "<td>{$row["boatType"]}</td>";
    $rows .= "<td>{$row["boatEngine"]}</td>";
    $rows .= "<td>{$row["boatLength"]}</td>";
    $rows .= "<td>{$row["boatWidth"]}</td>";
    $rows .= "<td>{$row["ownerName"]}</td></tr>";
}

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th><th>Boat</th><th>Engine</th><th>Length</th><th>Width</th> 
        <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
    <?= $rows; ?>
</table>
```

So the number in the 'ID' column should be a clickable link to display the data of that row.

Regards.

Comment: if i understood your question you have to change first row in this one:     
$rows .= "<tr><td><a href='yourPath/file.php?id='".$row["id"]." '>".$row["id"]."</a></td>";

the file.php control with $_GET['id'] isset and after you can do the query where id=...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$rows .= "<tr><td><a href='https://link.to/somewhere?id='".$row["id"]."'>".$row["id"]."</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below code .. it's bit easy and simple than above.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Boat</th>
        <th>Engine</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>Width</th> 
        <th>Owner</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='https://link.to/somewhere?id=<?= $row["id"]; ?>'><?= $row["id"]; ?></a></td>
            <td><?= $row["boatType"]; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["boatEngine"]; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["boatLength"]; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["boatWidth"]; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["ownerName"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```